# Unable to Debug Event Receiver

Tags: event-receivers, debugging

I have create custom content type using that content type I have created list in site.

Now trying to develop event receiver on list item events.
but now I'm unable to debug the code .

[image]

**Updated**
Here is the message display on break opint
[image]

Comment: You need more details... Are you able to deploy your solution? Is a break point not being hit?

Comment: What is the problem? Any mark in the breakpoint?

Comment: I have updated question by adding message display on break point

Comment: hi bunzab, I am able to deploy solution.  but break point not hit.

Comment: also I have try to  apply debugger  using F5 still its not working

Comment: it looks like not hit the breakpoint, are you tried to debug it before that debugged successfully and now not working ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to do the following to hit your breakpoint

- Retract your solution.
- Perform `IISRESET`.
- Deploy it again.
- Set your breakpoint and make sure it's not disabled.
- Open SharePoint Portal.
- Attached Visual Studio project to the `w3wp.exe` processes
- Choose `managed code` in the attach to process dialog.
- Try to delete an item from your list , that should hit your breakpoint now.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, Followed all this. But no luck. any specific thing i need to do...